# How do I override PXFilteredProcessingJoin in a graph extension without altering behavior of the base graph?

Tags: acumatica

**Background:**

In APPayBills (Payables - Prepare Payments) the screen functionality is designed to accumulate all payments for a cash account.  There is a selection for Branch, but it doesn't actually limit payments to the branch, but rather the cash accounts defined for the branch.

Our use case is that we have multiple "branches" that operate somewhat independently for day to day business (inventory, issuing material, purchase receipts, etc.)  However, all the payables are handled via a single bank account, hence a single cash account.  Payments are processed by branch according to certain business rules.  The obvious way to handle this under standard Acumatica would be to use different bank accounts so that we can operate separate cash accounts inside of Acumatica.  Our user base prefers the single bank account, so we are tasked with creating a solution.  We have some work arounds also, but this needs to be streamlined to ease the burden on staff and reduce errors.  A case was opened with Acumatica, and the response was that this requires a customization on our part.

**Problem:**

APPayBill utilizes 2 views (APDocuemntList and APExceptionsList) to populate grids on 2 tabs.  Standard behavior is that the grid remains empty until the Branch, Payment Method, and Cash Account are entered by the user.  At that point, the results are displayed in the grids according to all payments using the specified cash account.

My understanding is that you can redefine a view in a graph extension to overrides it.  However, when I do, the grids fill in even before any selections are made.  The grid data is filtered as I want them, but change in user interface behavior for when to populate the grids is undesirable.

**Before Code:**

```
[PXFilterable]
public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<APAdjust, PayBillsFilter,
    InnerJoin<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>, And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>>>,
    LeftJoin<APTran, On<APInvoice.paymentsByLinesAllowed, Equal<True>,
        And<APTran.tranType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>,
        And<APTran.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>,
        And<APTran.lineNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdLineNbr>>>>>>>
    > APDocumentList;

public PXSelectJoin<APAdjust,
    InnerJoin<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>, And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>>>,
        LeftJoin<APTran, On<APInvoice.paymentsByLinesAllowed, Equal<True>,
            And<APTran.tranType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>,
            And<APTran.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>,
            And<APTran.lineNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdLineNbr>>>>>>>
    > APExceptionsList;
```

**After Code:**

```
[PXFilterable]
public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<APAdjust, PayBillsFilter,
    InnerJoin<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>, And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>>>,
    LeftJoin<APTran, On<APInvoice.paymentsByLinesAllowed, Equal<True>,
        And<APTran.tranType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>,
        And<APTran.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>,
        And<APTran.lineNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdLineNbr>>>>>>>

    // BEG - Add branch filter
    ,Where<APAdjust.adjdBranchID, Equal<Current<PayBillsFilter.branchID>>>
    // END - Add branch filter

    > APDocumentList;

public PXSelectJoin<APAdjust,
    InnerJoin<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>, And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>>>,
        LeftJoin<APTran, On<APInvoice.paymentsByLinesAllowed, Equal<True>,
            And<APTran.tranType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>,
            And<APTran.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>,
            And<APTran.lineNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdLineNbr>>>>>>>

    // BEG - Add branch filter
    ,Where<APAdjust.adjdBranchID, Equal<Current<PayBillsFilter.branchID>>>
    // END - Add branch filter

    > APExceptionsList;
```

To be sure that the addition of the where clause was not the culprit, I literally copied and pasted the exact views from the base code into the graph extension so that there would be absolutely no change.  Surprisingly (to me) the graph extension with the replacement views exhibited the same pre-populating behavior that was seen with the Where clauses added.

Clearly there is something special to overriding views in this way.  I tried with and without [PXOverride] decorating the views with no difference in behavior.

What is causing the processing screen to pre-populate the grid, and how do I apply my overrides to the 2 views properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the graph APPayBills, the data view *APDocumentList* is defined like this:

```
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<APAdjust, PayBillsFilter, 
        InnerJoin<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.docType, Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>, And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>>>>> APDocumentList;
```

However, the view also has a delegate:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable apdocumentlist()
        {
            PayBillsFilter filter = Filter.Current;

            if (filter?.PayDate == null || filter.PayTypeID == null || filter.PayAccountID == null)
                yield break;

            foreach (APAdjust adj in APDocumentList.Cache.Inserted)
            {
                APInvoice doc = PXSelect<APInvoice, Where<APInvoice.docType, Equal<Required<APInvoice.docType>>, And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<APInvoice.refNbr>>>>>.Select(this, adj.AdjdDocType, adj.AdjdRefNbr);
                adj.SeparateCheck = (adj.SeparateCheck ?? doc.SeparateCheck);
                yield return new PXResult<APAdjust, APInvoice>(adj, doc);
                if (_copies.ContainsKey(adj))
                {
                    _copies.Remove(adj);
                }
                _copies.Add(adj, PXCache<APAdjust>.CreateCopy(adj));
            }

            PXSelectBase<APInvoice> cmd = ComposeBQLCommandForAPDocumentListSelect();

            int startRow = PXView.StartRow;
            int totalRows = 0;

            APDocumentListViewExecuteParamsBuilder.ViewExecutingParams viewExecutingParams =
                new APDocumentListViewExecuteParamsBuilder()
                    .BuildViewExecutingParams(APDocumentList.View);

            foreach (PXResult<APInvoice, CurrencyInfo> res in
                cmd.View.Select(new[] { filter },
                                ComposeParametersForAPDocumentListSelect(),
                                PXView.Searches,
                                viewExecutingParams.Sorts.ToArray(),
                                viewExecutingParams.Descendings.ToArray(),
                                viewExecutingParams.FilterRows.ToArray(),
                                ref startRow,
                                PXView.MaximumRows,
                                ref totalRows))
            {
                APInvoice doc = res;
                APAdjust adj = new APAdjust();
                adj.VendorID = doc.VendorID;
                adj.AdjdDocType = doc.DocType;
                adj.AdjdRefNbr = doc.RefNbr;
                adj.AdjgDocType = APDocType.Check;
                adj.AdjgRefNbr = AutoNumberAttribute.GetNewNumberSymbol<APPayment.refNbr>(Caches[typeof(APPayment)], new APPayment { DocType = APDocType.Check });
                adj.SeparateCheck = doc.SeparateCheck;

                if (APDocumentList.Locate(adj) == null)
                {
                    PXSelectJoin<APInvoice, InnerJoin<CurrencyInfo, On<CurrencyInfo.curyInfoID, Equal<APInvoice.curyInfoID>>>, Where<APInvoice.docType, Equal<Required<APInvoice.docType>>, And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<APInvoice.refNbr>>>>>.StoreCached(this, new PXCommandKey(new object[] { adj.AdjdDocType, adj.AdjdRefNbr }), new List<object> { res });
                    PXSelectorAttribute.StoreCached<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>(APDocumentList.Cache, adj, doc);
                    yield return new PXResult<APAdjust, APInvoice>(APDocumentList.Insert(adj), doc);

                    _copies.Add(adj, PXCache<APAdjust>.CreateCopy(adj));
                }
            }

            APDocumentList.Cache.IsDirty = false;
            APDocumentList.View.RequestRefresh();
        }
```

When a delegate is explicitly defined (such as this case), the information populated in the screen is the one defined in the delegate.

In this case, this condition is the one that does not populate the grid until the filter parameters are entered:

```
if (filter?.PayDate == null || filter.PayTypeID == null || filter.PayAccountID == null)
                    yield break;
```

In your case, you need to override the delegate as well.

**Note**: this is the view and delegate definition for 2018R2. Other versions may differ. Make sure you use the one that applies for your version.